# What is API equivalent of 'az account list'?

Tags: java, azure, rest, api, command-line-interface

I am trying to list all the subscriptions of a logged in user. Something that 
$ az account list 
provides. I am looking for REST API equivalent or Java SDK equivalent.

What am I missing here?

Every time I use the URL 
    https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2019-06-01
It returns only 1 subscription.

expecting something like following

```
[

  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "87654321-de26-zzzz-b714-184nd94h1000",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "Test2",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "12345678-3333-4444-8787-000000111111",
    "user": {
      "name": "foo@hotmail.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
  },
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "id": "12345678-4321-1234-4444-111111000000",
    "isDefault": false,
    "name": "Test1",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "88888888-4444-3333-1111-010101010101",
    "user": {
      "name": "foo@hotmail.com",
      "type": "user"
    }
  }
]
```

and run perform something equivalent of following commands. Of course inlot more details.

```
$ az account set -s 87654321-de26-zzzz-b714-184nd94h1000
$ az vm list
$ az account set -s 12345678-4321-1234-4444-111111000000
$ az vm list
```

I am using service principal and other Tenant invited the user as guest user.

One of the main requirement is not using browser based initial login since this application will work as a daemon.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you logged in, such as the Azure CLI, it will get all the information of the current user, both the tenants and the subscriptions in the tenants. But when you use the REST API, there is a default tenant, so you just can list all the subscriptions of the default tenant. For you, the default tenant has only one subscription.

You can use the CLI command `az login` with the parameter `--debug` to see more details about the process. And also can use the REST API https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2016-06-01 to get all the tenants your account has.

Comment: I debugged 'az login' as suggested. It seems the login process performs 

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com:443 "POST /<tenant-id>/oauth2/token

and then GET subscriptions using

https://management.azure.com:443 "GET /subscriptions?api-version=2016-06-01

which also means as long as I have a list of all tenant-ids I just have to perform above two steps for all of them and consolidate the list of subscriptions to form a json.
Let me know if there is anything more to this. 
thank you for the pointer.

Comment: @Prasad So if it solves your problem please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Prasad Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know if you need more help?

Comment: After trying around few things , realized that this is half the story/question. I think I need to understand and may be ask here explicitly what I am trying to achieve as end goal.
I am writing a service that will connect to collect say VM configuration data from various subscriptions in different azure tenants. 
I have a Service principle created and got some test tenants invite me (user) as Guest User.
Once I get the Subscriptions list as in original question I can collect data. 
No login process involving browser though as the CLI forces.

Comment: @Prasad Firstly, my answer makes you know what you really want, so you need to mark my answer. Secondly, the question you want to ask is different from this, you need to ask another issue in SO and you still do not exactly describe what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Never used azure cli before, but is this what you are looking for?

[Subscription - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/subscription/list)